# Deep Reinforcement Learning Python agent vs random

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to develop a game like agent vs random using deep reinforcement learning. I am having a problem with the training part of the agent. Can anyone figure out what the problem is?

play.py

```
from drl import ReplayMemory, train_agent, agent
from main import print_board, print_results, player2_random_move

board_size = 7

player1_pieces = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (6, 4), (6, 6)]
player2_pieces = [(6, 0), (6, 2), (0, 4), (0, 6)]


def play_game():
    board = [[' ' for _ in range(board_size)] for _ in range(board_size)]

    for piece in player1_pieces:
        x, y = piece
        board[x][y] = '▲'

    for piece in player2_pieces:
        x, y = piece
        board[x][y] = '●'

    memory = ReplayMemory(10000)

    global player1_score, player2_score, valid_move

    print("Current board:")
    print_board(board)

    train_agent(5, 50, board, agent, agent, memory, board)


play_game()
```

drl.py

```
from collections import namedtuple, deque
import random

import numpy as np

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

from main import player2_random_move, print_results, print_board
from utils import is_valid_move, capture_after_move, move_piece, board_size, check_game_over, reset_game, \
    determine_winner

epsilon = 0.05

BATCH_SIZE = 64

NEGATIVE_REWARD = -1.0
POSITIVE_REWARD = 1.0
CAPTURE_REWARD = 5.0
WIN_VALUE = 10.0
DRAW_VALUE = 3.0
LOSS_VALUE = -5.0

BOARD_SIZE = 7

INPUT_SIZE = 49
OUTPUT_SIZE = 49
HIDDEN_SIZE = 196

LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
EPSILON_START = 1.0
EPSILON_END = 0.01
EPSILON_DECAY = 0.995
TARGET_UPDATE = 10

Experience = namedtuple('Experience', ('state', 'action', 'next_state', 'reward'))


class ReplayMemory:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.memory = deque([], maxlen=capacity)

    def push(self, state, action, next_state, reward):
        self.memory.append(Experience(state, action, next_state, reward))

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory)


def board_to_state(board):
    state = np.zeros((BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE))
    for x in range(BOARD_SIZE):
        for y in range(BOARD_SIZE):
            if board[x][y] == '▲':
                state[x][y] = 1
            elif board[x][y] == '●':
                state[x][y] = -1
    return state.flatten()


class DQNAgent(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DQNAgent, self).__init__()

        self.dl1 = nn.Linear(INPUT_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE)
        self.dl2 = nn.Linear(HIDDEN_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(HIDDEN_SIZE, OUTPUT_SIZE)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.dl1(x)
        x = torch.relu(x)

        x = self.dl2(x)
        x = torch.relu(x)

        x = self.output_layer(x)
        x = torch.sigmoid(x)
        return x


agent = DQNAgent()
target_agent = DQNAgent()
target_agent.load_state_dict(agent.state_dict())

optimizer = optim.Adam(agent.parameters(), lr=0.001)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()


def select_action(state, agent, output_size, epsilon):
    if random.random() < epsilon:
        return random.randint(0, output_size - 1)  # Random action
    else:
        state_tensor = torch.from_numpy(state).float().unsqueeze(0)
        with torch.no_grad():
            action_probs = agent(state_tensor)
        return torch.argmax(action_probs).item()


def decode_action(action, board):
    piece_index = action // (BOARD_SIZE ** 2)
    move_index = action % (BOARD_SIZE ** 2)

    move_x = move_index // BOARD_SIZE  # X-coordinate of the move
    move_y = move_index % BOARD_SIZE  # Y-coordinate of the move

    piece_coords = find_piece_coordinates(piece_index, board)

    return (*piece_coords, move_x, move_y)


def decode_action_destination(action, board):
    x = action // BOARD_SIZE  # row
    y = action % BOARD_SIZE  # column

    return x, y


def find_piece_coordinates(piece_index, board):
    player1_pieces = [(x, y) for x in range(len(board)) for y in range(len(board)) if board[x][y] == '▲']

    if piece_index < len(player1_pieces):
        return player1_pieces[piece_index]
    else:
        return player1_pieces[0] if player1_pieces else (0, 0)


def apply_action_to_game(action, board, state, step):
    player1_piece_coords = [(x, y) for x in range(board_size) for y in range(board_size) if board[x][y] == '▲']
    reward = 0
    move_made = False

    if len(player1_piece_coords) == 1:
        while not move_made:
            x1, y1 = random.choice(player1_piece_coords)  # Rastgele bir taş seç
            x2, y2 = decode_action_destination(action, board)

            if is_valid_move(board, x1, y1, x2, y2, '▲'):
                move_piece(board, x1, y1, x2, y2, "player1")
                move_made = True
                reward += POSITIVE_REWARD
                if capture_after_move(board, '▲', '●') == 1:
                    reward = CAPTURE_REWARD
            else:
                reward = NEGATIVE_REWARD
                action = select_action(state, agent, OUTPUT_SIZE, epsilon)
                # print("Agent selected an invalid move. Trying another move.")

    else:
        for _ in range(2):
            move_made = False
            while not move_made:
                state = board_to_state(board)
                action = select_action(state, agent, OUTPUT_SIZE, epsilon)
                x1, y1, x2, y2 = decode_action(action, board)

                if is_valid_move(board, x1, y1, x2, y2, '▲'):
                    move_piece(board, x1, y1, x2, y2, "player1")
                    if capture_after_move(board, '▲', '●') == 1:
                        reward = CAPTURE_REWARD
                    else:
                        reward = POSITIVE_REWARD  # Geçerli hamle için pozitif ödül
                    move_made = True
                else:
                    reward = NEGATIVE_REWARD
                    # print("Agent selected an invalid move. Trying another move.")
                # print("Reward", reward)

    done = 9
    done = check_game_over(board)

    if (step == 49):
        done = determine_winner(board)

    if done == 0:
        reward = reward + DRAW_VALUE
    elif done == 1:
        reward = reward + WIN_VALUE
    elif done == 2:
        reward = reward + LOSS_VALUE

    return board_to_state(board), reward, done


def compute_loss(predicted_q_values, target_q_values):
    return F.mse_loss(predicted_q_values, target_q_values)


def train_agent(episodes, max_steps_per_episode, board_main, policy_net, target_net, memory, board):
    # loop episodes
    for episode in range(episodes):
        eps = max(EPSILON_END, EPSILON_START * (EPSILON_DECAY ** episode))

        # reset_game(board)
        for step in range(max_steps_per_episode):

            if check_game_over(board) == 9:
                print(f"ROUND {step + 1}")
                state = board_to_state(board_main)
                print_board(board)
                action = select_action(state, policy_net, OUTPUT_SIZE, eps)
                new_state, reward, done = apply_action_to_game(action, board_main, state, step)
                memory.push(state, action, new_state, reward)

                if len(memory) > BATCH_SIZE:
                    experiences = memory.sample(BATCH_SIZE)

                state_tensor = torch.from_numpy(state).float().unsqueeze(0)
                predicted_q_values = policy_net(state_tensor)

                new_state_tensor = torch.from_numpy(new_state).float().unsqueeze(0)
                target_q_values = target_net(new_state_tensor)

                loss = compute_loss(predicted_q_values, target_q_values)

                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()

                state = new_state

                if episode % TARGET_UPDATE == 0:
                    target_agent.load_state_dict(agent.state_dict())

                if done != 9:
                    break

                print_results()

                player2_random_move(board)
                print_results()

        board = reset_game(board)


def evaluate_agent(episodes, board_main):
    win_count = 0
    for _ in range(episodes):
        state = board_to_state(board_main)
        done = False
        while not done:
            action = select_action(state, agent, OUTPUT_SIZE, 0.1)
            state, reward, done = apply_action_to_game(action, board_main)
            if done and reward > 0:
                win_count += 1
    return win_count / episodes


def save_model(model, filename='model.pth'):
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), filename)


def load_model(model, filename='model.pth'):
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(filename))
    model.eval()
```

utils.py

```
board_size = 7
player1_score = 0
player2_score = 0


def move_piece(board, x1, y1, x2, y2, player):
    board[x2][y2] = board[x1][y1]
    board[x1][y1] = ' '
    print(f"{player} move from ({x1}, {y1}) to ({x2}, {y2})")


def capture_after_move(board, player_symbol, opponent_symbol):
    global player1_score, player2_score

    top_wall = [(0, i) for i in range(board_size)]
    bottom_wall = [(board_size - 1, i) for i in range(board_size)]
    left_wall = [(i, 0) for i in range(board_size)]
    right_wall = [(i, board_size - 1) for i in range(board_size)]

    i = 1
    while i < 3:

        # i = 1 ise player1 , i = 2 ise player2
        if (i == 1):
            opponent_pieces = [(x, y) for x in range(board_size) for y in range(board_size) if
                               board[x][y] == player_symbol]
            player_pieces = [(x, y) for x in range(board_size) for y in range(board_size) if
                             board[x][y] == opponent_symbol]
        else:
            player_pieces = [(x, y) for x in range(board_size) for y in range(board_size) if
                             board[x][y] == player_symbol]
            opponent_pieces = [(x, y) for x in range(board_size) for y in range(board_size) if
                               board[x][y] == opponent_symbol]

        for piece in player_pieces:
            x, y = piece
            neighbors = [(x - 1, y), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1), (x, y + 1)]

            # topwall
            capture_conditions_top_wall = [
                ((x + 1, y) in player_pieces and (x + 2, y) in player_pieces and (x + 3, y) in player_pieces and (
                    x + 4, y in opponent_pieces)),
                ((x + 1, y) in player_pieces and (x + 2, y) in player_pieces and (x + 3, y) in opponent_pieces),
                ((x + 1, y) in player_pieces and (x + 2, y) in opponent_pieces),
                ((x + 1, y) in opponent_pieces)
            ]

            for condition_top, removal_indices_top in zip(capture_conditions_top_wall,
                                                          ([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0])):
                if piece in top_wall and condition_top:
                    for idx in removal_indices_top:
                        capture_score(player_symbol, board[x + idx][y])
                        board[x + idx][y] = ' '  # Oyuncunun taşını kaldır
                    print(f"Player {player_symbol} captured opponent's pieces.")
                    return 1
            # bottomwall

            capture_conditions_bottom_wall = [
                ((x - 1, y) in player_pieces and (x - 2, y) in player_pieces and (x - 3, y) in player_pieces and (
                    x - 4, y) in opponent_pieces),
                ((x - 1, y) in player_pieces and (x - 2, y) in player_pieces and (x - 3, y) in opponent_pieces),
                ((x - 1, y) in player_pieces and (x - 2, y) in opponent_pieces),
                ((x - 1, y) in opponent_pieces)
            ]

            for condition_bottom, removal_indices_bottom in zip(capture_conditions_bottom_wall,
                                                                ([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0])):
                if piece in bottom_wall and condition_bottom:
                    for idx in removal_indices_bottom:
                        board[x - idx][y] = ' '  # Oyuncunun taşını kaldır
                    print(f"Player {player_symbol} captured opponent's pieces.")
                    return 1

            # leftwall

            capture_conditions_left_wall = [
                ((x, y + 1) in player_pieces and (x, y + 2) in player_pieces and (x, y + 3) in player_pieces and (
                    x, y + 4) in opponent_pieces),
                ((x, y + 1) in player_pieces and (x, y + 2) in player_pieces and (x, y + 3) in opponent_pieces),
                ((x, y + 1) in player_pieces and (x, y + 2) in opponent_pieces),
                ((x, y + 1) in opponent_pieces)
            ]

            for condition_left, removal_indices_left in zip(capture_conditions_left_wall,
                                                            ([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0])):
                if piece in left_wall and condition_left:
                    for idy in removal_indices_left:
                        board[x][y + idy] = ' '  # Oyuncunun taşını kaldır
                    print(f"Player {player_symbol} captured opponent's pieces.")
                    return 1

            # rightwall

            capture_conditions_right_wall = [
                ((x, y - 1) in player_pieces and (x, y - 2) in player_pieces and (x, y - 3) in player_pieces and (
                    x, y - 4) in opponent_pieces),
                ((x, y - 1) in player_pieces and (x, y - 2) in player_pieces and (x, y - 3) in opponent_pieces),
                ((x, y - 1) in player_pieces and (x, y - 2) in opponent_pieces),
                ((x, y - 1) in opponent_pieces)
            ]

            for condition_right, removal_indices_right in zip(capture_conditions_right_wall,
                                                              ([0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0])):
                if piece in right_wall and condition_right:
                    for idy in removal_indices_right:
                        board[x][y - idy] = ' '  # Oyuncunun taşını kaldır
                    print(f"Player {player_symbol} captured opponent's pieces.")
                    return 1
        i = i + 1

    # iki taşın arasında sıkışma durumu...

    for neighbor1 in neighbors:
        for neighbor2 in neighbors:
            if (
                    neighbor1 in opponent_pieces
                    and neighbor2 in opponent_pieces
                    and (x * 2 - neighbor1[0], y * 2 - neighbor1[1]) == neighbor2
            ):
                for op_piece in opponent_pieces:
                    a, b = op_piece
                    op_neighbors = [(a - 1, b), (a + 1, b), (a, b - 1), (a, b + 1)]
                    for op_neighbors1 in op_neighbors:
                        for op_neighbors2 in op_neighbors:
                            if (
                                    op_neighbors1 in player_pieces
                                    and op_neighbors2 in player_pieces
                                    and (a * 2 - op_neighbors1[0], b * 2 - op_neighbors1[1]) == op_neighbors2
                            ):
                                board[x][y] = ' '
                                # player +1
                                board[a][b] = ' '
                                # player -1
                                print(f"Player {player_symbol} captured opponent's pieces.")
                                return 1

                board[x][y] = ' '  # Oyuncunun taşını kaldır
                # player +1
                print(f"Player {player_symbol} captured opponent's pieces.")
                return 1


def is_valid_move(board, x1, y1, x2, y2, player_symbol):
    if (x1 == x2 and abs(y1 - y2) == 1) or (y1 == y2 and abs(x1 - x2) == 1):
        if 0 <= x2 < board_size and 0 <= y2 < board_size:
            if board[x2][y2] == ' ':
                if board[x1][y1] == player_symbol:
                    return True
    return False


def get_valid_moves(board, x1, y1, player_symbol):
    # Bu fonksiyon, verilen bir taş için tüm geçerli hamleleri döndürür
    valid_moves = []

    # Tüm olası hareket yönlerini kontrol et: yukarı, aşağı, sol, sağ
    directions = [(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)]  # (dx, dy) formatında

    for dx, dy in directions:
        x2, y2 = x1 + dx, y1 + dy
        if is_valid_move(board, x1, y1, x2, y2, player_symbol):
            valid_moves.append((x2, y2))

    return valid_moves


def capture_score(player_symbol, board_symbol):
    global player1_score, player2_score

    if player_symbol == "▲":
        if board_symbol == "▲":
            player1_score -= 1
        else:
            player1_score += 1
    else:
        if board_symbol == "●":
            player2_score -= 1
        else:
            player2_score += 1


def check_game_over(board):  # 0-draw 1-player1 2-player2 9-no over
    if not any(cell in ['▲', '●'] for row in board for cell in row):
        print("It's a draw! No pieces left on the board.")
        return 0

    # Oyunculardan birinin tüm taşlarını kaybettiği durumu kontrol et
    if not any(cell == '▲' for row in board for cell in row):
        print("Player 2 wins! Player 1 has no pieces left.")
        return 2

    if not any(cell == '●' for row in board for cell in row):
        print("Player 1 wins! Player 2 has no pieces left.")
        return 1

    return 9


def determine_winner(board):
    player1_count = sum(row.count('▲') for row in board)
    player2_count = sum(row.count('●') for row in board)

    if player1_count == player2_count:
        print("It's a draw! Player1 and Player2 has same number of pieces.")
        return 0
    elif player1_count > player2_count:
        print("Player 1 wins! Player 1 has more pieces.")
        return 1
    else:
        print("Player 2 wins! Player 2 has more pieces.")
        return 2


def reset_game(board):

    for x in range(board_size):
        for y in range(board_size):
            board[x][y] = ' '

    player1_pieces = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (6, 4), (6, 6)]
    player2_pieces = [(6, 0), (6, 2), (0, 4), (0, 6)]

    for piece in player1_pieces:
        x, y = piece
        board[x][y] = '▲'

    for piece in player2_pieces:
        x, y = piece
        board[x][y] = '●'

    return board
```

main.py

```
from utils import capture_after_move, is_valid_move, move_piece, get_valid_moves, board_size

import random

epsilon = 0.05  # veya başka bir uygun başlangıç değeri

player1_score = 0
player2_score = 0


def human_move(board):
    print("Player 2's turn:")
    print("You have the following pieces: ●")

    player2_piece_coords = [(x, y) for x in range(board_size) for y in range(board_size) if board[x][y] == '●']

    if len(player2_piece_coords) == 1:
        print(f"You have only one piece at {player2_piece_coords[0]}.")
        print("Enter the destination coordinates (x, y):")
        x2, y2 = map(int, input().split())

        if is_valid_move(board, player2_piece_coords[0][0], player2_piece_coords[0][1], x2, y2, '●'):
            move_piece(board, player2_piece_coords[0][0], player2_piece_coords[0][1], x2, y2, "player2")
            capture_after_move(board, '●', '▲')
        else:
            print("Invalid move. Try again.")
            return False
    else:
        print(f"You have the following pieces: {player2_piece_coords}")
        print("Enter the coordinates of the first piece to move (x, y):")
        x1, y1 = map(int, input().split())

        print("Enter the destination coordinates for the first piece (x, y):")
        x2, y2 = map(int, input().split())

        if is_valid_move(board, x1, y1, x2, y2, '●'):
            move_piece(board, x1, y1, x2, y2, "player2")
            capture_after_move(board, '●', '▲')
            print("Current board:")
            print_board(board)

            while True:
                print("Enter the coordinates of the second piece to move (x, y):")
                x3, y3 = map(int, input().split())

                print("Enter the destination coordinates for the second piece (x, y):")
                x4, y4 = map(int, input().split())

                if is_valid_move(board, x3, y3, x4, y4, '●'):
                    move_piece(board, x3, y3, x4, y4, "player2")
                    capture_after_move(board, '●', '▲')
                    break
                else:
                    print("Invalid move. Try again.")
                    continue

        else:
            print("Invalid move. Try again.")
            return False

    return True


def player2_random_move(board):
    player2_pieces = [(x, y) for x in range(board_size) for y in range(board_size) if board[x][y] == '●']
    if not player2_pieces:
        return False

    piece_to_move = random.choice(player2_pieces)
    x1, y1 = piece_to_move

    valid_moves = get_valid_moves(board, x1, y1, '●')

    if not valid_moves:
        return False

    if len(player2_pieces) == 1:
        move = random.choice(valid_moves)
        x2, y2 = move

        move_piece(board, x1, y1, x2, y2, "player2")
        capture_after_move(board, '●', '▲')
    else:
        for _ in range(2):
            piece_to_move = random.choice(player2_pieces)
            x1, y1 = piece_to_move

            valid_moves = get_valid_moves(board, x1, y1, '●')

            if not valid_moves:
                return False

            move = random.choice(valid_moves)
            x2, y2 = move

            move_piece(board, x1, y1, x2, y2, "player2")
            capture_after_move(board, '●', '▲')

    return True


def print_board(board):
    board_size = len(board)
    horizontal_line = "----" * board_size + "---"

    col_numbers = "    " + "   ".join(str(i) for i in range(board_size))
    print(col_numbers)

    for row_num, row in enumerate(board):
        print(horizontal_line)
        # Satır (row) numarasını yazdır
        print(f"{row_num} |", end="")
        for cell in row:
            print(f" {cell} |", end="")
        print()

    print(horizontal_line)


def print_results():
    global player1_score, player2_score
    print(f"Player 1 (▲) Score: {player1_score}")
    print(f"Player 2 (●) Score: {player2_score}")
```

I want to develop the agent so that it learns after every move. I aimed to do this in the train_agent function but I failed. I think there might be a problem with my select_action function.